# Are questions about semantic HTML on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-contents

We've had a couple of questions recently about semantic HTML. One was migrated to Stack Overflow, an the other is moving in that direction.

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/page-title-h2-in-navigation-menu-markup-two-birds-one-stone
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11841/what-is-the-semantically-correct-way-to-create-an-accordion-widget

Obviously, questions about how to write code to implement a UI are off-topic. The majority of HTML questions asked on Stack Overflow would not fit here.

But when the question isn't about how to write HTML so that it looks right or works right in a GUI browser, but rather about the semantics of the markup, doesn't it qualify as an accessibility question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of those topics that can arguably included in the realm of user experience design when you argue that everything is part of the user experience.

In the interests of scope and of putting questions in the best place for them to get good answers, though, I think almost all implementation questions would be best served by Stack Overflow's userbase.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think how to write code is a topic of UX. Semantic code is better for accessibility and SEO but still it's related to code. SO if someone is asking how to write a semantic code then it's should be move to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions, I think, in the decision about where to put or move a question. Firstly, where does the concept and context fit - and anything in the realms of HTML or the front end of a forms application would then fit on here. However the other issue is where questions are most likely to get the best and most appropriate answers. Sometimes, this is SO rather than UX, because the userbase on SO may have more insight into the technical details.

Sometimes, thought, there are two questions one for each. I think this makes it a difficult choice.

Edit: to clarify.

The point I was trying to make is, as @Charles points out, that everything affect the UX, and so, from that point of view, everything could be considered to fit on this site. BUT - and this is critical - the specific focus of each site means that the BEST place for a particualar question is not always here. It means that there is a need to focus questions towards the appropriate site.

Sometimes - maybe often - questions that are quite wide are best reconsidered and split into multiple questions on multiple sites.

Comment: Why exactly do you think `anything in the realms of HTML` belongs here? UX is not HTML coding. Far from it.

Comment: No, but the presentation of HTML to a user - what a site looks like, and how it behaves, is. Getting the right html on the page is part of UX.

Comment: Then so is every piece of coding - from the lowest level to the highest. Every line of code affects what the site looks like and/or how it behaves. HTML is code and as such, it does not belong on this site.

Comment: Which was sort of my point.

Comment: Then you didn't do a very good job making that point. "where does the concept and context fit - and anything in the realms of HTML or the front end of a forms application would then fit on here." Sure looks like you are saying that HTML questions belong here.